# Can somebody explain the well-defined mapping to me?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $(X,(\langle.,.\rangle)$ be a Hilbert space over $\mathbb{K}$ with an orthonormal basis $(x_n)_{x\in\mathbb{N}}$ and let $(\lambda_n){n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset \mathbb{K}$ be a bounded sequence.The mapping $T:X\rightarrow X$ is defined by

$$ Tx:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\lambda_n\langle x,x_n\rangle x_n  , x\in\mathbb{X}$$

T is well-defined How can I prove?

I would appreciate if you answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The series is convergent: define for a fixed $x$, $S_N:=\sum_{n=1}^N\lambda_n\langle x,x_n\rangle x_n$. Then 
$$\lVert S_{M+N}-S_M\rVert^2=\sum_{j=M+1}^{M+N}|\lambda_n|^2\langle x,x_n\rangle^2\leqslant \sup_{k\in\mathbb N}|\lambda_k|^2\cdot\sum_{j=M+1}^{M+N}\langle x,x_n\rangle^2.$$
We conclude using Bessel's inequality.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how does that show that is well-defined? I have trouble with this concept too and I don't understand how your answer is related to that.

Comment: We have to prove that the series converge.